# database changes are lost in the next session

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

We just move to Amazon RDS. Now all the CREATE, UPDATE, and INSERT commands are reverting in the next session. All the tables are InnoDB and query caching is on. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [`autocommit` setting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html). It's possible that it's *disabled* (set to `off`) on your RDS instance and now all your uncommitted queries are getting rolled back because you're not explicitly committing.

Comment: Note that DDL statements are not affected by autocommit. They are statements that [implicitly commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

Comment: @BillKarwin Fair point, I was just going off what OP said when they mentioned `CREATE` statements. Thanks for that info. I just updated my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `autocommit=OFF` -- it can lead to forgetting to `COMMIT`, which leads to an automatic `ROLLBACK`.

Either have `autocommit=ON` or explicitly have pairs of `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

(This agrees with J.D.; I just want to add emphasis about this common mistake.)